# @InjectMocks, the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

When I use `@InjectMocks`, an exception was occurred. My code is shown below:

```
class A {
    private X x;
    private Y y;
    public A(String ip, int port) {
       this(someMethodCall(ip, port)); //
    }

    private A(X x) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = new Y();
    }
}
UT:
public class ATest() {
    @InjectMocks A a;
    @Mock X x;
    @Mock Y y;
    @Test ...
}
```

it will throw an NPE, can someone help me?

`org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'channel' of type 'class Juinit3.Channel'. You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance. However, the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception: null.`

Answer (score 17):

What this exeception is telling you...

> You haven't provided the instance at field declaration

In other words, you did not write...

```
@InjectMocks 
A a = new A("foobar", 123);
```

This would be completely acceptable and will probably solve your problem. Please remember that mocks will NOT be initialized at that point, so it's fine if you really need an example `String` and `int` there, but not if you need to put mocks there. In other words, if you had a constructor that took an X and you would write new `A(x)` here, x would be null, since the `@Mock` annotation would not have been processed yet.

> so I tried to construct the instance

Because there was no instance (because you didn't provide one) it tried to create one, but...

> However, the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception: null

So, your constructor throws null. Seems like your `someMethodCall` relies on the arguments (port, most likely) given not to be null, but since they are `String` and `int`, Mockito has no idea what values to use there. Since `port` is a primitive type and Mockito does not handle those specifically, the problem is probably there - Mockito will try to put null there, which will throw an exception.

If your constructor matched X and Y, for example, Mockito would probably try to put the mocks there, but it doesn't. The constructor wants `String` and `int` and there are no mocks for them, so Mockito can only use default values and those are `null`, which is a problem in case of `port` (because of `int`).

So, what's the solution?

1) Either make your constructor null-safe, allowing to give a null-port there (and make sure that the ip string is also handled in a null-safe way).

2) Use the thing you didn't use:

```
@InjectMocks 
A a = new A("foobar", 123);
```

In any case, it is not required to have all the depedencies in the constructor, Mockito will do fine injecting them into fields directly. So adding another constructor for X and Y is not a real solution. Of course, generally, constructor injection is preferable over field injection, but that's another topic.

As for your question about which constructor: The [documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.12.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) says this...

> the biggest constructor is chosen, then arguments are resolved with mocks declared in the test only

**Edit:** Seems that Mockito does not know how to handle primitive fields in constructors, what a shame.

Comment: I ended following the solution described at https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/

Answer (score 9):

The problem is with your `@InjectMocks` field. Since you did not initialize it directly like this:

```
@InjectMocks A a = new A("localhost", 80);
```

mockito will try to do constructor initialization. In this case it will choose the biggest constructor. In your case it's `public A(String ip, int port)`. If no mock fields as provided that will match the constructor arguments, the mockito will pass `null`s as a values for choosen constructor. So in this case the instance is initialized as `new A(null, null)`. In this case you will get `NPE`, since the second parameter of your constructor is `int`, and when the `null` will is going to be unboxed to `int` the `NPE` will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Either create a public non-args constructor or create `public A(X x, Y y)` constructor.

**2)** Make sure you use

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest() {
```

or

```
@Before
public void init(){
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Comment: I want to ask another question. Which constructor will be called when instantiate a @InjectMocks field? Is there any order? I have tried the constructor with parameters and the constructor without parameters,but I found that the call seems to have no rules.

Comment: The 2) cannot be the problem here, since if those were not present, nobody would do anything with `@InjectMocks` and thus no such exception would be the result, so we can deduce that one of those two is present.

Comment: Also the problem is not that x and y are not given into the constructor, since Mockito works fine with field injection, so the 2nd half of 1) cannot be the solution, too. Default constructor would work, though, but I would not add one just for tests.