# getting error during the @InjectMocks of the Class

Tags: java, junit, mockito

This is a service layer testing for a Service class but 
I am getting an error when using 
@InjectMocks on the class the test pom is 2.2.4 Release of Spring testing using Spring Boot.
getting error of misusing.InjectMocksException

```
RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class JobManagerServiceTest {
  private final String categoryFullPathId = "Main/Alexa Skills/For Your Smart Home";
  private final String vendorId = "vendor5";
  private final String filters = "filters12";
  private final Long frequency = 50000L;
  @InjectMocks
  JobManagerService jobManagerService;
  @Mock
  private ScrapperService scrapperService;
  @Mock
  private AppConfiguration config;
  @Mock
  private SlackClient slackClient;
  private ExecutorService executor;
  private BlockingQueue<Category> jobQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

 }
```

[image]
    @Service
    @Slf4j
    public class JobManagerService {

```
    private ScrapperService scrapperService;

    private AppConfiguration config;

    private ExecutorService executor;

    private SlackClient slackClient;

    private BlockingQueue<Category> jobQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();


    @Autowired
    public JobManagerService(AppConfiguration config, ScrapperService scrapperService, SlackClient slackClient) {
        this.config = config;
        this.scrapperService = scrapperService;
        this.slackClient = slackClient;
        this.executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(this.config.threadPoolSize);
    }
}
```

//Errors

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InjectMocksException: 
    Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'jobManagerService' of type 'class com.scrapper.jobmanager.service.JobManagerService'.
    You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
    However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : null

```
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:74)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:80)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1202)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Executors.java:89)
    at com.scrapper.jobmanager.service.JobManagerService.<init>(JobManagerService.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.FieldInitializer$ParameterizedConstructorInstantiator.instantiate(FieldInitializer.java:269)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.FieldInitializer.acquireFieldInstance(FieldInitializer.java:137)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.FieldInitializer.initialize(FieldInitializer.java:91)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.ConstructorInjection.processInjection(ConstructorInjection.java:46)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.MockInjectionStrategy.process(MockInjectionStrategy.java:68)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.MockInjectionStrategy.relayProcessToNextStrategy(MockInjectionStrategy.java:89)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.MockInjectionStrategy.process(MockInjectionStrategy.java:71)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.MockInjection$OngoingMockInjection.apply(MockInjection.java:92)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultInjectionEngine.injectMocksOnFields(DefaultInjectionEngine.java:25)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.injectMocks(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:79)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:42)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:69)
    ... 19 more
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You could test Spring Boot Test mocking. Use the SpringRunner.class instead of the MockitoRunner and `@MockBean` instead of `@Mock`. This should provide you with a SpringTestContext and allow autowiring in the test.

Comment: It's not working I tried

Comment: This looks like a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47465594/injectmocks-the-constructor-or-the-initialization-block-threw-an-exception

Answer (score 0):

The @InjectMocks immediately calls the constructor with the default mocked methods. I think `this.config.threadPoolSize` can't work there, because you can't stub a field. You should use a getter there:

```
public JobManagerService(...) {
    ...
    this.executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(this.config.getThreadPoolSize());
}
```

Then, you need to stub the getter before calling the constructor.
You can't do that if you use @InjectMocks, you can only do it if you initialize your test service in a setup method:

```
@Mock
private ScrapperService scrapperService;
@Mock
private AppConfiguration config;
@Mock
private SlackClient slackClient;

JobManagerService jobManagerService;

@Before
public void setup() throws IOException {
   when(config.getThreadPoolSize()).thenReturn(5);
   jobManagerService=new JobManagerService(config, scrapperService, slackClient)
}
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1314)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1202)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Executors.java:89)
 at com.scrapper.jobmanager.service.JobManagerService.<init>(JobManagerService.java:39)
 at com.scrapper.jobmanager.service.JobManagerServiceTest.setup(JobManagerServiceTest.java:40)

Comment: That's the exception you get when trying to create a threadpool of size 0. Did you change the constructor to use the getter iso of the field?

Answer (score 0):

I just change in this and now it's work

```
@PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        this.executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(this.config.threadPoolSize);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class JobManagerServiceTest {
    private final String categoryFullPathId = "Main/Alexa Skills/For Your Smart Home";
    private final String vendorId = "vendor5";
    private final String filters = "filters12";
    private final Long frequency = 50000L;
    private JobManagerService jobManagerService;

    @MockBean
    private ScrapperService scrapperService;

    @MockBean
    private AppConfiguration config;

    @MockBean
    private SlackClient slackClient;

    private ExecutorService executor;
    private BlockingQueue<Category> jobQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        this.jobManager Service = new JobManagerService(config, scrapperService, slackClient);
    }
}
```

It is not on class level but should work. Although I did not have the time to try it.

Comment: Why do you need to drag a framework into a Unit test?